# Store Data in Object recived via Retrofit

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit2

So I use Retrofit2 to get a JSON File and read it.

Part of the Data are Coordinates (blueCones and yellowCones) I want to Store in Objects and these Objects in an ArrayList.

How can I fit the Data in Objects and Store them in a List to use them later.

Json-File:

```
{
    "engineTemp" : "90",
    "speed" : "130",
    "blueCones":[{
            "x" : 6.0,
            "y" : 5.0
        },
        {
            "x" : 7.0,
            "y" : 7.0
        }
    ],
    "yellowCones":[{
            "x" : 11.0,
            "y" : 5.0
        },
        {
            "x" : 12.0,
            "y" : 6.0
        }
    ]
}
```

Interface:

```
interface JsonApi {

    @GET("/test.json")
    fun getAllData(): Call<Data>
}
```

Start Retrofit:

```
    val service = JsonParser.jsonParserInstance?.create(JsonApi::class.java)
    val call = service?.getAllData()

    call?.enqueue(object : Callback<Data>{
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<Data>, t: Throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Error reading JSON", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<Data>, response: Response<Data>) {
            val body = response.body()

            val engineTemp = body?.engineTemp
            val speed = body?.speed
            val blueCoordinates = body?.blueCones
            val yellowCoordinates = body?.yellowCones
        }
    })
}
```

Connection:

```
object JsonParser{
    private var retrofit: Retrofit? = null
    private val BASE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:80"

    val jsonParserInstance: Retrofit?

        get(){
            if(retrofit==null){
                retrofit = retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build()
            }
            return retrofit
        }
}
```

Blue and Yellow Cone classes:

```
data class BlueCone(var x: Double, var y: Double)

data class YellowCone(var x: Double, var y: Double)
```

Comment: that `JsonParser` is non-sense. just use the `GsonConverter` ...as it is meant to be used (this requires adding annotations to the class to be converted into... which @Advice-Dog's answer lacks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Gson, you can easily map your JSON to your Objects. It uses the variable's name to map by default, so I just followed your naming scheme.

First, you only need one `Cone` class.

```
data class Cone(
    val x: Float,
    val y: Float
)
```

And then you can create a class to contain the entire response.

```
data class MyResponse(
    val engineTemp: String,
    val speed: String,
    val blueCones: List<Cone>,
    val yellowCones: List<Cone>
)
```

And with your interface, you can set the class.

```
@GET("/test.json")
fun getAllData(): Call<MyResponse>
```